# RAD Version: 8.5.1

Tags: websphere

I am having RAD Version: 8.5.1 and websphere version 8.5.0. While trying to configure server on RAD using correct installation directory I am getting error **"The WebSphere Application Server installation directory is not correct."**

Comment: Are you trying to create IBM WebSphere Portal 8 runtime server with WAS 8.5.0 in RAD? or runtime Web sphere Application server with WAS?

Comment: runtime websphere application server